# WPF vs Win App battery usage

Tags: wpf, battery, winapp

We want to use wpf application on tablet and looking for difference battery usage impacts between win app and wpf application?
Is there any comparision battery usage or document?

Comment: Why don´t you test the app yourself? There is no oraculum that would provide such an information to you.

Comment: A better question would be why this really matters? You're never more than 10ft away from a plug socket anyway. Most laptop/tablet batteries last for most of the day, it's unlikely you will be using a machine for 10 hours straight unless you were gaming. That being said, who games for 10 hours on a tablet?

Comment: There are many reasons/applications for using a machine 10 hours straight! I have built mobile industrial systems that have such requirements. And it is a legit question: maybe someone out there has already done this. It is one of the great reasons for SO: saving time by preventing duplicate effort.

Answer (score 1):

I doubt there is any type of documentation on what you want, but as suggested above, running your own tests shouldn't be too hard. I don't [recall the APIs](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/search/en-us/windows?query=battery%20information&Refinement=183), but on any mobile device, there are going to be battery state objects you can access giving, at the very least, remaining battery energy. Write two test apps, each using the different paradigms. Run each, one at a time and for a long duration. Check on the energy usage at the beginning and end.

Answer (score 1):

This is late for an answer but one aspect to remember about battery consumption is the use of the radios (Bluetooth and WiFi).

For tablet apps try to manage your app by stepping back and analyzing what data you'll need from the database and try to get the data in one shot so the OS can turn off the radio. If you make an sql call each time the user presses a button then the radio is on more and drains the battery. The OS might also leave the radio on "a little longer" in case you make another query.

For the rest of the UI of the app, you're safe to count on an 8 hr shift and then they dock it for recharge.

You can watch for the battery notifications as well so you can save the info in the app before the OS shuts you down.

Other than that, each app is unique and you'll need to run these tests during your QA cycle.